# simple form input request in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

all i am trying to do here is making ajax request to the database as the user types in  zipCode to see if it is available or not

it is just i need it to make the call once the input field is 5 digits no less, if the code exists in the database a little Green check mark should appear, if not a red X mark is the mark to appear

```html
<input type="text" ng-model="checkname">
```

Comment: What is the question?  Can you post your javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You need a listener of textbox change event:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="zip" ng-change="zipChanged()" />
```

And then in your Angular controller:

```
function MyController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.zipChanged = function () {
        // would be better to use regex to check zip format.
        if ($scope.zip.length === 5) {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/checkZip/' + $scope.zip
            }).then(function(response) {
                // Check response and show red or green mark.
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Note, you don't request the database directly via the Ajax. Ajax helps you to communicate to a server in async style. So you will also need a REST server with action `/checkZip/{zip}` that checks your zip code against the database and returns response.

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding ngChange and then check the length

```
<input type="text" ng-model="checkname" ng-change="checkname()">
```

then in your controller

```
$scope.checkname = function(){
    //check the length of your variable and do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple [custom async validator](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation) which will do the check. This has the advantage that it will work with the built-in Angular validation to make it easier to show error messages or prevent the form being posted back.

This involves using a directive to add a validation function to the `$asyncValidators` of the `ng-model` controller. This function will make the `$http` request and return its promise. If this is valid then validation will pass, otherwise it will fail.

Here is a working sample with a mock `$http` call. It will only pass if the zip is "90210".

```js
(function() {

  var app = angular.module('myapp', [])
  
  app.controller('ctrl1', function($scope) {
    $scope.myField = "";
  });
  
  app.directive('zipCheck', function($q) {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
        // add an async validator to the form's validators
        ctrl.$asyncValidators.zipCheck = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
  
          // don't validate if empty or less than 5 chars
          if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue) || modelValue.length < 5) {
              return $q.resolve();
          }
          
          // the actual http call
          /*
          return $http.get('/checkZip?zip='+modelValue)
            .then(function(response) {
              // handle response as appropriate
              return response == "valid";
            });
          */
  
          // simulate the http request
          var deferred = $q.defer();
          window.setTimeout(function() {
            if(modelValue == "90210") {
              deferred.resolve();
            }
            else {
              deferred.reject();
            }
          }, 500);
          return deferred.promise;
            
        };
      }
    };
  });

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="ctrl1">

  <form name="myForm">
    <!-- note the zip-check attribute - this is the validation directive -->
    Zip Code: <input name="myField" ng-model="myField" zip-check />

    <!-- validation feedback - checking, invalid, valid -->
    <span ng-show="myForm.myField.$pending.zipCheck">...</span>
    <span ng-show="myForm.myField.$error.zipCheck">✖</span>
    <span ng-show="myField.length >= 5 && myForm.myField.$valid">✔</span>
  </form>

</div>
```